# How to log space taken by all SQLAlchemy queries?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

I'm using SQLAlchemy as an ORM on top of PostgreSQL for a Flask app in Heroku.

I'm getting "memory limit exceeded" errors (R14) from Heroku, and one theory is that some of the queries to the ORM are returning very large result sets (thousands of rows or more) that are taking up too much memory.  I am using the `.all()` method in some of my queries, so this is quite possibly the problem.

Is there a way to automatically log how many rows are returned by every SQLAlchemy query, or possibly even the amount of memory taken by every result set?